# Where to store user-specific persistent data in R package

Tags: r, package

Say I have package where the user initialized variables that get stored as tables of data.  I would like this data to then be available in all the subsequent sessions.  Where should this data be stored?  I would prefer that it gets stored in the same location as the rest of the package data, so when `library(pkg)` is called, the data is loaded.  Is there a way to modify the package data or sysdata in such a way that this would work?

Comment: It's somewhat risky, but you might be able to just chuck it into the `pkg/data` file like a built-in dataset ([like the ones here](https://github.com/bokeh/rbokeh)), although I'm not quite sure if you need to use `delayedAssign` to turn it into a promise. Alternately, you could promise it through `.Rprofile`, but making the promise conditional on loading `pkg` would require considerable contortions.